# NTP not syncing immediately on windows

Tags: ntp

I am trying to sync with NTP server, but server is responding with below messages.
Below are the wireshark captures.

```
Flags: 0x0c
11.. .... = Leap Indicator: unknown (clock unsynchronized) (3)
..00 1... = Version number: NTP Version 1 (1)
.... .100 = Mode: server (4)
Peer Clock Stratum: unspecified or invalid (0)
Peer Polling Interval: invalid (0)
Peer Clock Precision: 0.000008 sec
Root Delay:    0.0000 sec
Reference Timestamp: Jan  1, 1970 00:00:00.000000000 UTC
```

My ntp.conf file has below enteries:

```
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 0
restrict 127.127.1.0
```

After some 3 minutes the sync is happening properly.But its not happening immediately.
Can anybody help me in resolving.

Answer (score 0):

The `fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 0` line is telling ntp that your local server has the accuracy of an atomic clock. I doubt this is the case...

My guess is that your local clock is being used as a time source because of this line.

I believe that 0 should be a 10, which will tell ntp that unless there is another server in your ntp.conf that has a better time source(a higher stratum), do not use your local clock as a time source. This line is typically added to be used as a last resort.

ntp typically takes around 3 to 5 minutes to sync by default. Two things that can speed this up:

- Use the iburst option in your ntp.conf
- Manually sync to a time source using ntpd -gq